# TinySort plugin problems

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins

I'am trying to sort div elements with the plugin TinySort 1.5.6 . But he doesn't work. My code is :

```
<div id="ticketlist">               
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket1" data-price="7921.90">.....</div>
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket2" data-price="8000.00">.....</div>
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket3" data-price="3200.00">.....</div>
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket4" data-price="5234.23">.....</div>
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket5" data-price="4322.26">.....</div>
     <div class="ticket" id="ticket6" data-price="4234.25">.....</div></div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#ticketlist .ticket').tsort('div',{data:'price'});
```

Comment: Any javascript errors in your console? What does happen when that javascript is called? Anything?

Comment: Sorting is happens, but wrong. For example: 8000 -> 5234.23 -> 7021.90->4234.25 -> 4322.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('#ticketlist div.ticket').tsort({data:'price'});`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b1Ltvu2/1/)